# ServiceProxy.Create asking for primary returns secondary replica instead

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-actor

I am accessing a service with remoting, from different actor types. They do this through shared code in their base class, calling ServiceProxy.Create method.

I have use cases for accessing both primary and secondary replicas, and use the method overload where the TargetReplicaSelector is specified. This normally works just fine.

After doing an upgrade of the service (without changes to code, just testing out how doing upgrade at runtime affects communication), some of the actors (always the same type!) get a reference to a **secondary replica** when calling ServiceProxy.Create, even though I am specifically asking for the *primary* replica with TargetReplicaSelector.PrimaryReplica parameter.
Other actor types keep getting the primary as they should.

How is this possible?

**Edit 1:** I know that during the upgrade, the primary will become secondary, and any of the secondaries will become primary. I can see this in Explorer during the upgrade.

So it seems like ServiceProxy.Create - when called from some actor types- is keeping some stale information about which replica is primary?
I though that ServiceProxy would automatically detect these changes?
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit2:** I found this comment to [this service remoting doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting):

> Yongjun Dec 7, 2016 how to dispose/disconnect to the remote service,
>
> in our product, in stateful service A, it will connect to another
>   stateful service B through ServiceProxy.Create
>
> but after service A switch over, it still has the connection to
>   service B by using "netstat -ano", and if service A switch to primary
>   again, it will has two connection to service B

Seems to be the same problem.

**Question:** How is this problem avoided?

Comment: Looks like this is being discussed in the SF Issues GitHub https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/192

Comment: I did not find a real solution to this. But after upgrade to latest runtime and SDK version it eventually managed to resolve the address, even though the problem still was there for a while after service upgrade. After putting more than one of the stateful services into an application, the problem disappeared altogether.